# Unable to get property 'offset' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

I have made a Load More feature for the ads

In Chrome and FireFox there are no issues, when I try and select in IE (version 10) the following JavaScript error is showing:
"Unable to get property 'offset' of undefined or null reference"
I think I have invoked a method or property on an object of a type other than Object, or I passed an argument of a type other than Object when an Object was required.
So I tried below codes which did not help :

```
function findElementTotalOffset(obj) {
    var oleft = otop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            oleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            otop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return {left : oleft, top : otop};
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

```
import $ from "jquery"
class LazyLoadAds {
  constructor() {
    this.initLazyLoad = this.initLazyLoad.bind(this)
    this.initLazyLoad()
  }
  initLazyLoad() {
    let self = this,
    listener = self.throttle(300, function () {
        slotsAtlantic.forEach(function (item) {
            let $item = $('#' + item.id)



  if ($item.length) {
              let $parent = $item.parent(),
              index = slotsAtlantic.indexOf(item)
              if ($parent.is(':visible') && ((window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) >= ($parent.offset().top - $(window).height() - 300))) {
                  googletag.cmd.push(function () {
                      googletag.pubads().refresh([item.slot]);
                  });
                  slotsAtlantic.splice(index, 1);
              }
            }
        });
    });
    window.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
  }

  throttle(delay, callback) {
    var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
    return function () {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
            previousCall = time;
            callback.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    };
  }
}

export default LazyLoadAds
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get an element which has no parent element.

So when you write: `let $parent = $item.parent()`, $parent is null.

The exception is launched when you want to get `$parent.offset()`.

Did you try to log every elements you get ?